# Why is Terraform not picking up locals.tf?

Tags: terraform

Here are my files so far.

### main.tf

```
data "my_vars" "vars" {
    certificate_arn = local.certificate_arn
}
```

### variables.tf

```
variable "certificate_arn" {
    description = "The ARN for the certificate"
    type = string
}
```

### locals.tf

```
locals {  
    certificate_arn = "foo"
}
```

When I run a plan, Terraform asks me for the value of `certificate_arn`, however as far as I can see it is set in locals. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

## Because you made it a variable!

This one confused me for a minute too.  Your `locals` are defined correctly.  You reference it correctly.  So why is terraform prompting for it?  Just because you define it as a variable.

Since you're not using `var.certificate_arn` anywhere, defining it is a variable is not needed.  But since you did define it as a variable, terraform is going to diligently ask for it.  Getting rid of the variable definition should fix your issue.

If later you want to turn it into a variable, fine.  But you'll need to get rid of the local and reference `var.` instead of `local.`.

Comment: AH. I saw somewhere that variables.tf is for declaring and locals.tf is for assigning. I will have to find that question and update it with your answer! Thanks!

Comment: You can put it all in the same file too.  Terraform doesn't care much what the files are named.